# No puedo ejecutar mi copia de seguridad Wordpress en XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

He creado exportado la base de datos de wordpress del servidor y los archivos de wordpress mediante FTP. Luego instalé XAMPP, cree una base de datos a nivel local, luego importé la de wordpress en phpmyadmin y cree dentro de la carpeta de XAMPP/htdocs llamada 8navasprueba y ahí es donde metí los ficheros de wordpress. Y por último modifique el fichero wp-config con los datos de la nueva base de datos y poniendo en servidor localhost pero no me ejecuta cuando pongo la ruta en el navegador.

[image: resultado]

Comment: Cuál es la url?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/8navasprueba es donde tengo todo los archivos de WordPress en la carpeta dentro del XAMP

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress fija valores de rutas (url) de la instalación original en la base de datos. Tienes que hacer una conversión de algunos datos antes de importarla al nuevo host. Pero si ya hiciste la importación, se puede arreglar haciendo un par de `querys`.

Primero. En la raíz de wordpress abrir el archivo `wp-config.php` y editar las lineas con los valores del nuevo host.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'nombre_de_la_db' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'usuario_de_la_db' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'pass_de_la_db' );
```

Segundo. Actualizar la base de datos. Desde PHPMyAdmin ejecutar las siguiente consultas. 
Obvio, reemplazas `old_url` con la url antigua y `new_url` debe ser 
 `http://localhost:8080/8navasprueba`

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_url', 'new_url') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_url','new_url');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'old_url','new_url');
```

[*Nota] Si no has hecho la importación, también puede funcionar `buscar y reemplazar` los valores descritos desde un editor de código, en los respectivos archivos SQL, y luego importar.